# Linq-to-entities, Generics and Precompiled Queries

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-entities

I'm experimenting with linq and generics. For now, I just implemented a GetAll method which returns all records of the given type.

```
class BaseBL<T> where T : class
{
    public IList<T> GetAll()
    {
        using (TestObjectContext entities = new TestObjectContext(...))
        {
            var result = from obj in entities.CreateObjectSet<T>() select obj;
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. Next, I would like to precompile the query:

```
class BaseBL<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<ObjectContext, IQueryable<T>> cqGetAll =
    CompiledQuery.Compile<ObjectContext, IQueryable<T>>(
      (ctx) => from obj in ctx.CreateObjectSet<T>() select obj);

    public IList<T> GetAll()
    {
        using (TestObjectContext entities = new TestObjectContext(...))
        {
            var result = cqGetAll.Invoke(entities);
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, i get the following:

```
 base {System.Exception} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[admin_model.TestEntity] CreateObjectSet[TestEntity]()'
 method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}
```

What is the problem with this? I guess the problem is with the result of the execution of the precompiled query, but I am unable to fanthom why.

Comment: Why do you think you need a compiled query for that?  You don't need it.

Comment: Not related to the error; but if it *did* work, you would want to make `cqGetAll` a `static` field

Comment: @Jeff Mercado - I don't need it for this case, but i plan to expand this with more complex queries

Comment: @Marc Gravell - I am unable to do that because the class is generic. But I plan to compile the queries on first request and cache them at class level for each type.

Comment: @loodakrawa static fields work fine with generics and are per-T; there's no reason that can't be `static`

Comment: @Marc Gravell - You are right. I was so focused on my current problem that I forgot that only parameters are generic. Thanx!

Comment: I had this exception when I used methods inside the LINQ query that are not part of the entity model. My guess is that the precompiled query can't invoke the `CreateObjectSet` for the type `TestEntity` because the precompiled query is not part of the context that is used to invoke it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this exception when I used methods inside the LINQ query that are not part of the entity model. The problem is that the precompiled query can't invoke the `CreateObjectSet` for the type `TestEntity` because the precompiled query is not part of the context that is used to invoke it.

Comment: It seems so. I get the same exception when using precompiled queries in combination with CreateObjectSet. That means this has nothing to do with generics.